# Get all the values from the first left table but when two left joins used its restricting the values from first table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, where-clause

I am trying to get all the values from the first left table but when I use two left joins its restricting the values from first table.

I used the below query

```
SELECT P.person_id, TS.Task_Id, TS.skill 
FROM Person P 
LEFT JOIN Person_Skill PS ON P.person_id = PS.person_id 
LEFT JOIN Task_Skill TS ON PS.Skill = TS.Skill 
WHERE ts.task_id = 245
```

I need all the person id from person table.

Answer (score 3):

Just move the condition on the left joined table from the `where` clause to the `on` clause of the join:

```
select p.person_id, ts.task_id, ts.skill 
from person p 
left join person_skill ps 
    on p.person_id = ps.person_id 
left join task_skill ts 
    on  ps.skill = ts.skill 
    and ts.task_id = 245       --> here
```

Rationale: conditions in the `where` clause are mandatory. If there is no match in `ts`, then condition `ts.task_id = 245` cannot be satisfied, since `ts.task_id` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the filter condition in a sub query instead of using it as a global filter outside. This should give you the output that you desire.

```
 SELECT P.person_id,TS.Task_Id,TS.skill FROM Person P 
 LEFT JOIN Person_Skill PS 
 ON P.person_id=PS.person_id 
 LEFT JOIN 
 (Select * from Task_Skill where task_id = 245) TS 
 ON PS.Skill=TS.Skill;
```